# nvd3.js : no mouseover datapoint effects in a line chart

Tags: graph, linechart, nvd3.js

I'm trying to draw a simple line chart using nvd3/d3. The transition that occurs on the datapoints during 'mouseover' are not visisble. How to fix this?.

adding the code below:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
    return this;
};

function getData(transport) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < transport.length; i++) {
        arr.push({
            x : new Date(transport[i].timePeriod).addHours(7),
            y : transport[i].number
        });
    }
    return arr;
}

function cumulativeTestData(transport) {

    return [{
        key : "Active Customers",
        values : getData(transport),
        color : "#ff7f0e"
    }];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart;
    chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    }).y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format("%d-%m-%y")(new Date(d));
    });

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',g'));
    d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(cumulativeTestData(transport))
    //  .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
        nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    return chart;
});

$(function() {
    $("#day").click(function() {
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var to = $("#to").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://api.local/api/GraphData?startDate=" + from + "&endDate=" + to,
            type : 'GET',
            contentType : "application/javascript",
            crossDomain : true,
            dataType : "jsonp",
            cache : false,
            async : false,
            success : function(transport) {
                //  nv.addGraph(drawGraph(transport));
                drawGraph(transport);
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("failed in calling status");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If i run this code separately, i can see the data points but as I have to include this graph with many other controls, data points doesnt seem to be working.

also want to add that when i click on a particular data point on the line chart, i see this error in the console of fire bug

Error: Invalid value for  attribute cx="NaN"

Comment: What is the X value you are passing in your JSON ? Can you update the question with a snippet of your JSON.

Comment: [{"number":195,"timePeriod":"2013-05-28T00:00:00"},{"number":204,"timePeriod":"2013-05-27T00:00:00"},{"number":44,"timePeriod":"2013-05-26T00:00:00"},{"number":93,"timePeriod":"2013-05-25T00:00:00"},{"number":160,"timePeriod":"2013-05-24T00:00:00"},{"number":163,"timePeriod":"2013-05-23T00:00:00"},{"number":195,"timePeriod":"2013-05-22T00:00:00"}]                                                                                       This is my JSON data.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is when I use data returned by JSON for making graph and click on data points, I get    <circle cx="268.6666666666667" cy="60.49999999999997" r="2.256758334191025" class="nv-point nv-point-4"></circle>   but when I use hard coded values i get <path class="nv-path-7" d="M113.62463924974953,-10.000000000000004L-9.999999999999986,-10.000000000000002L-10,66.3209876541134L36.174505472652356,111.46939300485637L79.84952069375453,88.75425506326863L131.0795278200065,29.823005034326474Z"></path>. And hard coded values do show data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to change the your JSON structure so either **`number`** becomes **`y`** and **`timePeriod`** becomes **`x`** , so its can be accessible by data that is been passed into the **`lineChart()`**:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    }).y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });
```

If you are using :

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format("%d-%m-%y")(new Date(d));
    });
```

the date should be returned in **UNIX TIME STAMP** FORMAT. If you are NOT sending a **UNIX TIME STAMP** just use **`chart.xAxis.tickFormat()`**.

I have a sample code running in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/EgJjn/) just have a look.

Finally you need a data structure  similar to this.

```
data = [{
    "values" : [{
        "x" : 1025409600000,
        "y" : 0
    }, {
        "x" : 1028088000000,
        "y" : 0.09983341664682815
    }, {
        "x" : 1030766400000,
        "y" : 0.19866933079506122
    }, {
        "x" : 1033358400000,
        "y" : 0.29552020666133955
    }, {
        "x" : 1036040400000,
        "y" : 0.3894183423086505
    }],
    "key" : "Line 1",
    "color" : "#ff7f0e"
}, {
    "values" : [{
        "x" : 1025409600000,
        "y" : 0.5
    }, {
        "x" : 1028088000000,
        "y" : 0.4975020826390129
    }, {
        "x" : 1030766400000,
        "y" : 0.4900332889206208
    }, {
        "x" : 1033358400000,
        "y" : 0.477668244562803
    }, {
        "x" : 1036040400000,
        "y" : 0.46053049700144255
    }],
    "key" : "Line 2",
    "color" : "#2ca02c"
}]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks...it worked. I only had to convert utc time to utc time stamp.

Comment: this worked great - but dont forget to use the Javascript version of the Unix timestamp (the above example is) which is in milliseconds.  


tl dr : the online converters I used to get Unix timestamp needed to be *1000 to function properly.


more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/BW2V5A5iHSo